# Get all text but not the regex match

Tags: php, html, tags

**Hi :)**

I try to get all text which does not match the regex,
I use PHP

My regex is :

```
/(<[^>]+>)/is
```

I would get all the text inside the HTML tag

I tried : `(?!(<[^>]+>))`  before and a lot of stuff...

The input :

```
<html><head><title>Nice page</title></head>
<body>Hello World <a href=http://cyan.com title="un lien">Ceci est un lien</a> <a>sdfaf</a>
<br /><a href=http://www.riven.com> Et ca aussi <img src=wrong.image title="et encore ca">dd</a>
</body></html>
```

I want match all text inside html tag with regex,

Like :

" Nice page
Hello World Ceci est un lien sdfaf
Et ca aussi dd "

Thanks !! :)

Comment: Share the code, pls and add more detail.

Comment: Please put an example of what you try to achieve then it would be more easy to understand and help

Comment: this it for specific tag, i would have a regex for all tag

Comment: I will never miss a chance to post this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3578036

Answer (score 2):

Use DOMDocument to do that:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($yourstring);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach($xp->query('//text()') as $textNode) {
    echo $textNode->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This regexp should select all the text content, part by part:

`/>([^<]+)/g`

Answer (score 0):

There is an `strip_tags()` function that does it without further configurations

```
<?php
$input = '<html><head><title>Nice page</title></head><body>Hello World <a href=http://cyan.com title="un lien">Ceci est un lien</a><a>sdfaf</a><br /><a href=http://www.riven.com> Et ca aussi <img src=wrong.image title="et encore ca">dd</a><body></html>';
print( strip_tags($input) );
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem of `strip_tags` is that it concatenate all the text without a separator, that gives things like: `Nice pageHello World...`